# Get data inside paypal returned objects

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I am integrate Paypal payment into my Laravel objects with Paypal SDK. The amount has passed to paypal and after users finished the payment. Paypal will return an objects, i am trying to get the data inside the returned objects but not successful. Here is the data after i dd out. i need to get the data inside of "payer" and "transactions"such as amount, currency and etc. Anyone can help me please?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal returns an object that is formatted using its own internal `fromJSON()` function - in the OP's case it was called from the Payment class:

```
$json = $call->execute(array('PayPal\Rest\RestHandler'), "/v1/payments/payment/{$this->getId()}/execute", "POST", $payLoad);
$ret = new Payment();
$ret->fromJson($json);
return $ret;
```

To use this as a `JSON` object, you need to use the `toJSON()` function:

```
$execution = new PaymentExecution();
$execution->setPayerId($_GET['PayerID']);
//Execute the payment
// (See bootstrap.php for more on `ApiContext`)
$result = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext);
// use the result 
$jsonResult = $result->toJSON();
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475286/how-to-access-transaction-data-from-the-paypal-sdk)